# stuck python while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, break

I am having trouble getting my while loop to break. I'm trying to move the circle from the starting point, right until it gets to the edge of the window. I can get it to move, but then it doesn't stop moving. I've tried different types of loops, and even adding a break, but it still won't break:/

```
from time import *
from graphics import *
from random import *
win = GraphWin("My Program", 500,400)

def MoveRight(circle):
    circle_center = circle.getCenter()
    center_x = circle_center.getX()
    center_y = circle_center.getY()
    circle.draw(win)
    for center_x in range(center_x, 450):
        circle.move(10,0)
        sleep(.15)
    circle_center = circle.getCenter()

my_circle = Circle(Point(200,50), 20)
my_circle.setFill("blue")
MoveRight(my_circle)
```

EDIT:
This has been resolved!

Comment: Which `while` loop? Note: It's probably never a good idea to `from ... import *` from several modules.

Comment: Your `for` loop executes 250 times (`center_x` taking on values from 200 to 450), but is moving 10 pixels at each step for a total of 2500 pixels of moment.  In other words, `center_x` no longer represents the position of the circle after the first step.  It might behave more like you expect if you used `circle.move(1, 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the center of the circle is at the 200 x-axis.
Then at the line:

```
 for center_x in range(center_x, 450):
```

center_x is equal to 200, the range between 200 (center_x) and 450 is 250.
Then this for loop will run 250 times.

So the rest of the code

```
circle.move(10,0)
sleep(.15)
```

is runned 250 times. So it will run 250 times 10 steps, 2500 steps !

To resolve your problem you should do this:

```
while center_x != 450:
    circle.move(10, 0)
    center_x += 10 # Added this
    sleep(.15)
```

**EDIT**:
I forgot to update the center_x...

(Keep in mind that the circle won't stop at the edge, it will stop at 450.
If the edge is at 450 then it should works.)

(The circle will not stop at 450, the center of this circle will.)

Comment: I tried that and it still wasn't stopping; then I realized that I hadn't been updating center_x . Once I did that, everything worked. Thanks much!

Comment: @RebeccaPhillips Can you mark your answer as resolved please ?